# Using shortest path pgr_dijkstra

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, shortest-path, dijkstra

Versions
PostGIS Bundle 3 for PostgreSQL x64 12
pgAdmin 4.24
pgrouting 3.1.0
I have also enabled the `postgis` and `pgrouting` extensions on a `public` schema.

I am only just starting with pgrouting so I am new to all the concepts. I am trying to follow a tutorial from pgrouting.org to find the shortest path between points on a network. I have created a table with their sample data and inserted the values.  I have created the edge table using:

```
CREATE TABLE edge_table (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    dir character varying,
    source BIGINT,
    target BIGINT,
    cost FLOAT,
    reverse_cost FLOAT,
    capacity BIGINT,
    reverse_capacity BIGINT,
    category_id INTEGER,
    reverse_category_id INTEGER,
    x1 FLOAT,
    y1 FLOAT,
    x2 FLOAT,
    y2 FLOAT,
    the_geom geometry


INSERT INTO edge_table (
    category_id, reverse_category_id,
    cost, reverse_cost,
    capacity, reverse_capacity,
    x1, y1,
    x2, y2) VALUES
(3, 1,    1,  1,  80, 130,   2,   0,    2, 1),
(3, 2,   -1,  1,  -1, 100,   2,   1,    3, 1),
(2, 1,   -1,  1,  -1, 130,   3,   1,    4, 1),
(2, 4,    1,  1, 100,  50,   2,   1,    2, 2),
(1, 4,    1, -1, 130,  -1,   3,   1,    3, 2),
(4, 2,    1,  1,  50, 100,   0,   2,    1, 2),
(4, 1,    1,  1,  50, 130,   1,   2,    2, 2),
(2, 1,    1,  1, 100, 130,   2,   2,    3, 2),
(1, 3,    1,  1, 130,  80,   3,   2,    4, 2),
(1, 4,    1,  1, 130,  50,   2,   2,    2, 3),
(1, 2,    1, -1, 130,  -1,   3,   2,    3, 3),
(2, 3,    1, -1, 100,  -1,   2,   3,    3, 3),
(2, 4,    1, -1, 100,  -1,   3,   3,    4, 3),
(3, 1,    1,  1,  80, 130,   2,   3,    2, 4),
(3, 4,    1,  1,  80,  50,   4,   2,    4, 3),
(3, 3,    1,  1,  80,  80,   4,   1,    4, 2),
(1, 2,    1,  1, 130, 100,   0.5, 3.5,  1.999999999999,3.5),
(4, 1,    1,  1,  50, 130,   3.5, 2.3,  3.5,4);
```

At this point I have created the geometry using:

```
UPDATE edge_table SET the_geom = st_makeline(st_point(x1,y1),st_point(x2,y2))
```

After that I create some topology with :

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('edge_table',0.001);
```

Then I try to use the pgr_dijkstra() function and it's at this point the wheels come off.

The textbook I'm following gives the following input as an example:

```
SELECT pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table', 16,9,false,false);
```

But it throws this error.

```
ERROR:  function pgr_dijkstra(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM ed...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

The table

Comment: That tutorial seems to be using a *pgRouting* version < 2.1 (or that versions signature was kept a while for backwards compatibility), since the main signature changed with that version; look closely at the [current docs](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html): `pgr_dijkstra('<edges_sql: TEXT>', <start_vid: ANYINTEGER>, <end_vid: ANYINTEGER>, <directed: BOOLEAN>)` - so one less `BOOLEAN` argument in your case.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: Your table should include: a column `start_vertex_id` and a column  `end_vertex_id`. So you should apply `pgr_dijkstra()` on the `vertex_id` and not the `edge_id`. So something like `pgr_dijkstra(edge_id, start_vertex_id, end_vertex_id, cost)`. Also the algorithm `dijkstra` do not support negative cost, so even if your implementation was correct, the execution will still fail.

Comment: @obchardon I fear that yo are somewhat mistaken...with that whole comment; the `edges_sql` query passed to the function should return a valid network topology (consisting of `edge_id`, `source`, `target` and `cost`, and optionally `reverse_cost`), while a negative `cost/reverse_cost` is a means to *exclude* a given edge from consideration, e.g. because it is not/you don't want it to be accessible in the given direction (or both directions). So changing the signature (effectively remove the last `false`) should be all you need to do.

Comment: Mant rhanks for the replies. I have now tried it with a different data and am getting results. Would selecting source and target nodes that had no solution cause a failure?